# Can this Java search be better written

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a better way to implement this string array and then do the loop. Better I mean more effeciant?

```
String[] knownWebClients = new String[]{"chrome", "firefox", "mozilla", "safari", "opera"};
 for (String nextKnown : knownWebClients) {
    if (uaType.toLowerCase().startsWith(nextKnown)) {
         this.uaWebType = uaType;
         this.uaType = "MyClient";
         }
      }
```

Comment: should post it here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally one can speed up "lookup activities" by simply using maps or sets. But given the that you do not ask for exact equality but "starts with" the is no possibility but iterating that list.

Two minor things:

- you can move that call to lowercase the input in front of the loop
- you can break the loop on match (to avoid iterating the remaining list items)

You could look into replacing the simple string comparison with a simple regular expression match - but I would be rather surprised if such a solution could be more efficient given this kind of matching.

Beyond that - are you sure you are focusing on a real issue. Unless this code executed many millions of times per minute - does it really matter if it needs 50 ns or 100? What I am saying is: don't try to fix non existing performance issues. Focus on writing well designed and human readable code.

Answer (score 2):

Your actual code makes more loops that required.

As soon as a matching is found you should stop and value your current object (this) but you go on looping and if you encounter new matching, you overwrite the current object with exactly the same values since there are invariant during the loop :

```
 this.uaWebType = uaType;
 this.uaType = "MyClient";
```

`uaType` is declared before the loop and "MyClient" is a constant.

Without streams, your code should be :

```
for (String nextKnown : knownWebClients) {
  if (uaType.toLowerCase().startsWith(nextKnown)) {
       this.uaWebType = uaType;
       this.uaType = "MyClient";
       break;
     }
 }
```

With streams, you could use `findFirst()` chained with `ifPresent()` to apply the processing once as soon a first matching occurs :

```
Arrays.stream(knownWebClients)
    .filter(known -> uaType.toLowerCase().startsWith(known))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent((s) -> {
        this.uaWebType = uaType;
        this.uaType = "MyClient";
    });
```

Comment: One day I should sit down and measure for such simple things if using streams gives a performance gain or a penalty. But well, as I have already written - is it really that important if this code needs 50 ns or 100ns? :-)

Comment: Call me when you do it :) I think that here the real difference is just the functional way to write the processing. Even if I think that it is not the best candidate for a refactoring. But I also suppose that my beginner way for using the stream and lambda (I learn it for about 1 month) is not still efficient enough.

Comment: You provide great content. Me reacts positive. People create sub standard lazy lousy messy content. Me not so positive any more. But I accept the challenge to focus on inner peace. Observe, give helpful constructive advise. Downvote close vote delete vote and shut up. Move on. That and 100k is my goal for the next 12 months.

Comment: That's what l wish you too : inner peace and a bloody rep !

Answer (score 0):

Move uaType.toLowerCase() out of cycle